# string returned in reading file line by line

Tags: php, file-io

I want to pass the string returned by reading a file line by line into a function. But its givin an unusual error.Seems as if the string returned is not exactly the line in the .txt file(source file).However if i manually pass strings into the function by copy pasting it works.heres ma code:-

```
 <?php
 function check($string)  {  //  for removing certain text from the file
 $x  =  0;
 $delete  =  array();
 $delete[0]  =  "*";
 $delete[1]  =  "/";
 for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
  $count=substr_count($string,$delete[$i]);
if($count>0){   
$x++;
return false;
break;
}
}
 if($x==0)return true;
 }
 $file = fopen("classlist.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $myFile = "new.txt";
 $fh = fopen($myFile, "w") or die("can't open file");
 while(!feof($file)){
 if(check(fgets($file))){
 $stringData = fgets($file);
 fwrite($fh, $stringData);
 }
 }
 fclose($fh);
 ?>
```

what i get on ma new.txt file is:line 2 line 4 line 6 line8---------- line 21
Plz help me out.....

Answer (score 2):

*Each* call to `fgets()` retrieves a new line from the file. Call it *once* per loop iteration, putting the returned line in a variable, and then check and use that variable.

Answer (score 2):

The while loop should look something more like this:

```
while(!feof($file)){
   $stringData = fgets($file);
   if(check($stringData)){
      fwrite($fh, $stringData);
   }
}
```

Because you're calling fgets twice, you're checking odd lines and writing out even lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your code so that you reduce the places where errors can occur, the `SplFileObject` is handy to operate with textfiles and to go over each line.

A `FilterIterator` can be used to only return those lines that do not contain `*` or `/`.

Example:

```
<?php

$inFile = "classlist.txt";
$myFile = "new.txt";

$outFile = new SplFileObject($myFile, 'w');

class LineFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        $line = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return strlen($line) === strcspn($line, '*/');
    }
}

$filteredLines = new LineFilter(new SplFileObject($inFile));

foreach($filteredLines as $line)
{
    $outFile->fwrite($line);
}

?>
```